# Conversion between Pandas Timestamp, DateTime, Unix Timestamp with Timezone / without Timezone Info

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, unix-timestamp

I created the following test case to understand the conversion of between DateTime to Pandas Timestamp, to Unix Timestamp, and back to DateTime, with and without TimeZone info, with Python 3.6

```
from unittest import TestCase

import datetime
from datetime import timezone
from pytz import timezone
import time
import pandas as pd

def test_date_with_timestamp_method(self):
    hkzone = timezone('Hongkong')
    dt_with_tz = datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 24, tzinfo=hkzone)
    dt_without_tz = datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 24)
    uts_with = dt_with_tz.timestamp()
    uts_without = dt_without_tz.timestamp()

    self.assertNotEqual(uts_without, uts_with)

    pd_with = pd.Timestamp(dt_with_tz)
    pd_without = pd.Timestamp(dt_without_tz)


    pd_unix_with_tz = pd_with.value // 10 ** 9
    pd_unix_without_tz = pd_without.value // 10 ** 9

    self.assertEqual(uts_with, pd_unix_with_tz)


    self.assertEqual(uts_without, pd_unix_without_tz)
```

I would like to ask why this assertion failed? The result of this is
    AssertionError: 1506182400.0 != 1506211200

```
    # convert back to datetime
    pd_dt_with_tz = pd_with.to_pydatetime()
    pd_dt_without_tz = pd_without.to_pydatetime()

    self.assertEqual(pd_dt_with_tz, dt_with_tz)
    self.assertEqual(pd_dt_without_tz, dt_without_tz)
```

And this line
    self.assertEqual(pd_dt_without_tz, dt_without_tz)
will result in this error.
AssertionError: datet[16 chars]7, 9, 24, 0, 46, tzinfo=) != datet[16 chars]7, 9, 24, 0, 0, tzinfo=)

So can I say it is the best practice to always put in back the timezone info to Datetime object before convert it to Timestamp?

Is it possible to make this two assertion success without timezone info?